# Prove that if $0<a<bx$ for all $x>1$ than $a \leq b$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing

I originally did a proof by contradiction for this question as follows:

Allow $a>b$. It follows that $ax>b$ for some $x>1$, which contradicts the original statement. Therefore, $a \leq b$.

I was informed this is not good enough to prove the question. Any tips or hints?

Comment: In fact, your conclusion contradicts "$ax\leq b$ for all $x>1$" which is not the original statement. To obtain a contradiction, your final conclusion should be "$a> bx$ for some $x> 1$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a>b$ and $x=\frac{a}{b}$.

Thus, $$a<b\cdot\frac{a}{b}=a,$$
which is contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For a contradiction, suppose $a>b$, then $a/b>1$. Let $x=a/b$ and now see what your original statement becomes.